# approximate spectrum ${\sigma}_{ap}$ of a bounded linear transformation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

if $\lambda\in{\sigma}_{ap}(T)$, where T is bounded linear transformation, how do i show that $|\lambda|≤\|T|\|$ ?

if $\lambda\in{\sigma}_{ap}(T)$, then for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $x\neq0$ such that $\|Tx−λx\|≤\varepsilon \|x\|$. I imagine that next it should be developed in some way to use the boundibility of T to conclude what is required, but I can't think of how to relate them, could someone give me a clue, or illustrate the path I should take?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\varepsilon> 0$ there is $x\ne 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon\|x\|\ge\|Tx-\lambda x\|\ge\big|\|Tx\|-|\lambda|\|x\|\big|\ge |\lambda|\|x\| - \|Tx\|.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
|\lambda|\|x\|\le\|Tx\| + \varepsilon\|x\|\le(\|T\| + \varepsilon)\|x\|.
$$
Dividing by $\|x\|\neq0$ gives $|\lambda|\le\|T\|+\varepsilon$. Letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ yields the desired result.

Comment: oh well, thank you very much for your help, I did not expect it, it did not occur to me to start with $\lambda$, however there is something that is still not clear to me, why it was necessary for T to be limited?

Comment: @ferphi You mean "bounded". If $T$ is not bounded, then $\|T\|$ does not exist (or, more loosely speaking, $\|T\|=\infty$). BTW, I edited my answer to make it better readable for you.

Comment: If it's true, I'm distracted, I'm sorry, really thank you very much, I loved your answer.

Comment: @ferphi I'm happy I could help.